# Access to Font at abcd.com has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: php, wordpress

I copy exact wordpress website from one domain to another domain. Now the website is running on both domains with same content and images. I stuck in wierd situation from last 24 hours. I am not getting the font icons on the website. I am getting cross origin error in the console. I try as many as possible things to make it fix

**1.** I try to add fonts differently in the header. But Not working

**2.** I try to allow it in header of php file

```
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header("access-control-allow-origin: http://www.abcdef.com/");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description');
```

**3.** I try to use wordpress cros plugin (which is outdated and not tested)

**4** I tried to clear the wordpress cache. Even I try to upload the website again.

But Nothing works. All this I try from the stackoverflow solutions.

Now Please help me regarding this

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Don't have absolute links to resources (ie ones that have the domain in them too), use ones like '/[font-name]' instead. That way it will use the same domain and protocol that the page requesting it is.

Also take a look at this existing question:

[CORS with php (Wordpress)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41036415/cors-with-php-wordpress)