# Getting multiple HTTP response headers for Wordpress site running on Apache2

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, http-headers, apache2

I am currently trying to configure the response headers for a Wordpress website.

**Web Server:** Apache 2

**Operating System:** Ubuntu 16.04

Right now, I have figured out that I am able to modify the HTTP response headers for the website through 3 different ways:

1. Configuring `apache2.conf` in `/etc/apache2`
2. Configuring the `.htaccess` file within the Wordpress directory

   (I do not have `mod_headers.c` therefore I cannot use this method)
3. Directly specifying the headers to use in the `header.php` file of the current Wordpress theme

Previously I set the website's response headers through directly specifying the HTTP headers in the `header.php` file (which contains all the scripts and whatnot to be used for each page). However right now, I'm trying to move all header configuration into `apache2.conf` such that all sites hosted on the server have the same response headers.

However, after restarting the Apache server, I am getting duplicate response headers even though I had removed all header declarations from the `header.php` file, and I am not sure why...

[image]

Because of security issues, the authorities of the main domain that my department's site is on is requiring us to only specify one instance of each HTTP header.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue, also, what are the best practices for setting HTTP response headers for sites hosted on an Apache 2 server?

Comment: Some of the plugins like w3totalcache allow you to set cashing and headers responses. Or look at the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41036415/cors-with-php-wordpress

Comment: @milenmk unfortunately, I am not able to install any more plugins as the organisation that the site is under has a limit to the number of plugins on each site…

Comment: Did you look at the proposed solution I've provided a link to? It uses a function() to set the headers in functions.php

Comment: @milenmk I am currently looking into that solution

Comment: you need mod_headers to do implement option 1 also i.e. "Configuring apache2.conf"